# Unable to install Wordpress on MAMP

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I recieve this error message when attempting to install Wordpress:

mamp has quit because of an unknown error. Please check the mamp pro error log inside the logs directory for more information.

Also, when attempting to change the MySQL password under the MySQL tab I recieve this error message:

mamp could not update mysql password. please check if mysql is running, check your configuration and try again.

Here are my error logs:

```
----apache----

[Thu Aug 11 14:54:25 2016] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:25 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:25 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:26 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.0.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:26 2016] [notice] Server built: May  6 2016 10:19:53
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:26 2016] [notice] Parent: Created child process 11620
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:27 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:27 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:28 2016] [notice] Child 11620: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:28 2016] [notice] Child 11620: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:28 2016] [notice] Child 11620: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 11 14:54:28 2016] [notice] Child 11620: Starting thread to listen on port 8888.
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:34 2016] [warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:34 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:34 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:35 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.0.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:35 2016] [notice] Server built: May  6 2016 10:19:53
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:35 2016] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4176
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:36 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:36 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:37 2016] [notice] Child 4176: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:37 2016] [notice] Child 4176: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:37 2016] [notice] Child 4176: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 11 14:55:37 2016] [notice] Child 4176: Starting thread to listen on port 80.

--------

----mysql----

160811 14:54:28 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160811 14:54:28 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160811 14:54:28  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160811 14:54:29 InnoDB: 5.5.49 started; log sequence number 1595675
160811 14:54:29 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 8889
160811 14:54:29 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160811 14:54:29 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160811 14:54:29 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160811 14:54:29 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.49-log'  socket: ''  port: 8889  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
160811 14:55:30 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

160811 14:55:30 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160811 14:55:30  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160811 14:55:31  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160811 14:55:31 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

160811 14:55:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160811 14:55:37 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160811 14:55:37  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160811 14:55:38 InnoDB: 5.5.49 started; log sequence number 1595675
160811 14:55:38 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160811 14:55:38 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160811 14:55:38 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160811 14:55:38 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160811 14:55:38 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.49-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
160811 15:01:46 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

160811 15:01:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160811 15:01:46  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160811 15:01:47  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
160811 15:01:47 [Note] C:\MAMP\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

--------
```

If you would be able to provide me with a solution to this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How does the `wp-config.php` file look like?

Comment: If MAMP has quit because of an unknown error, have you reinstalled (a newer version) MAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Event if MAMP quits, sometimes MySQL is running in the background. Could you kill all MySQL background process and try again?

1. Quit MAMP
2. Open the terminal and type: `killall -9 mysqld`
3. Restart MAMP